# How to make blog layout with Html Css

Tags: html, css, layout, blogs

I am a beginner in web designing. I know some basics about layout in CSS.
I am tried to create a blog post layout, given in the picture below.
[see image layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M10i0.png)
Please help me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! As heads up, usually you will want to come here for more specific questions to solve problems with your code, or to explain weird behavior you didn't quite understand. Your question is a little bit too open ended to be answered here but I can help you get started:

For starters, start thinking about translating every box in your picture into an HTML div. If you break each part of that picture into divs it can be a good foundation to add your css styling on top of. In your case, you might want something like this:

```html
<div id="articleList">
  <div id="article_1">
    <div id="articleImage_1">
      <img src="articleImage_1.jpg" alt="Picture #1">
    </div>
    <div id="articleContent_1">
      <div id="articleTags_1"></div>
      <div id="articleTitle_1"></div>
      <div id="articleAuthorNameAndCommentsSubheader_1"></div>
      <div id="articleBody_1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="article_2">
    <div id="articleImage_2">
      <img src="articleImage_2.jpg" alt="Picture #2">
    </div>
    <div id="articleContent_2">
      <div id="articleTags_2"></div>
      <div id="articleTitle_2"></div>
      <div id="articleAuthorNameAndCommentsSubheader_2"></div>
      <div id="articleBody_2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course you would be generating each row inside a for loop or .map() type function. You would also add in your .css in a 'class' attribute for every div.

Please let me know if you find this helpful by selecting my post as the answer, and don't be shy if you have any more questions :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know about boostrap than you can use this boostrap card to create that layout you want. Here is the sample code for it.

```
<div class="card w-50">
<div class="card-img-top d-flex align-items-center bg-light">
  <div>
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150/1f1a38/ffffff? 
       text=Image" alt="Card image cap">
  </div>
 <p class="col p-2 m-0">Text next to the right of the image</p>
</div>
</div>
```